# Facebook Connection Failed error in magento website?

Tags: facebook, magento

I have done following steps:-

1. created an facebook App with all the details filled and got AppID and App Secret.
2. Integrated an facebook extension to my magento website and filled AppID and App Secret to magento admin.

When I login then it asks for the permissions to access the facebook user details also, but after that it shows error "Facebook Connection Failed".

My website is at localhost and I filled site url = "http://localhost/magento/mywebsite.php" in the facebook App which I created.

I have done this thing prior also. It worked previously but not working this time.

Comment: Hey Connor, I did it earlier it worked fine,but now it is not working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use localhost URLs when configuring your app. The URL needs to be accessible to Facebook. Either use the IP address of your test server, or register a test domain.

Comment: Now i put site url = http://myIPAddress/magento/index.php/...but it is giving error:-API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration

Comment: The error is telling you what to do. Your app domain and site URL should share a route domain.

Comment: Hey thanks, my problem is solved by reinstalling magento and again doing same couple of things.